# Design and Construction of a Schmitt trigger by using NPN transistors

Tags: schmitt-trigger

[image: ****]

I try do  it using mutism but fail...anyone help

[image: what i get]
[image: I need this output]

Comment: what do you mean with you failed? can you be more detailed? What happens, what should happen instead?

Comment: i get wrong output. there are so many model of npn transistor in multisim....i m not sure  about which one to use

Comment: "wrong": What did you expect to get, what did you get instead? Details, please. Can't diagnose something we don't see.

Comment: I edit the post... the 1st  one i get...... the 2nd one is the right ans

Comment: what's what in these diagrams? What are the axes? Cutting off the axis labels seems to be a very bad idea.

Comment: voltage vs time

Comment: magnitude matters… I'm a bit tired asking for details you simply could not have excluded in the first place.

Comment: Sir i  give u the circuit i design.. the output(voltage[y axis] vs time[x axis]) i get and the output i want.... with due respect i don't understand what details i miss

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend playing around with the circuit a bit in the very helpful tool Falstad (which I am a mere thankful user of), found here
https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html

You can use it to visually see the flow of current and understand the principle of the circuit better.

To get you started - the following is a text source code for a Falstad model of a working Schmitt Trigger using NPN transistors. Click *File* and *Import from Text* and paste the below snippet.

```
$ 1 0.000005 100.89512123094175 61 5 43 5e-11
t 256 256 304 256 0 1 -3.0136483772690394 -1.5496496329591183 1000 default
R 304 160 304 96 0 0 40 5 0 0 0.5
r 304 240 304 160 0 500
r 304 272 304 352 0 330
g 304 352 304 384 0 0
t 384 240 432 240 0 1 0.6104834262138601 0.6453363086317025 1000 default
r 304 240 384 240 0 220
w 432 256 432 272 0
w 432 272 304 272 0
r 384 240 384 352 0 1200
r 432 224 432 160 0 1000
w 432 160 304 160 0
w 432 224 496 224 0
R 256 256 128 256 0 1 3 2.5 2.5 0 0.5
O 496 224 560 224 1 0
w 384 352 304 352 0
o 12 512 0 4099 4.999999999999997 0.0001 0 2 13 0
```

or click the following link to load the file automatically (it's embedded in the link, that's why it's so long)
https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcdoA4CcCwCYcGZJ0AWMAdiQDYIki8QEBTAWjDACgAXEbBC73kASL8+kcFGgUi6MBWzpS2VJDwJU6iRQrFsi9HlRgSs1MjggAJgwBmAQwCuAGw5sASoMjDZYoSHSioECIxJDEw6AQ2ACcPYWxg2PAKMPo4aMTdbETVLJ8CNgBzbIQs3wNhMM5BVDiE2iz4lIgmbGg8IiJsdvaEUnRsXEwQJhgiLTlkonIFPHI+MHhLGwdndN9G6tqUgcg2AHcgvAaBeu5FKH3DhvP1892Y8u4Ex5zAnDSY04HhU+83+Euv2SiT+uwOX3iQX83Ehu3cPD4CPAShEb0E3AiGNCEkiAHkoYjIbwxN9xGDNoISsVcmwAPbI+g4QLBdDoPzQVmcrnc0KwOAQEngOi7IA

Comment: i appreciate Ur effort sir.but i currently trying to learn using multisim

Comment: You can linkify falstad sims by using 'create link' in SE's text editor.

Comment: @hacktastical indeed, but i wanted to post a reasonable looking link to ensure people it was not spam or rickrolling or whatever :)

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough informations what exactly an output should be?
So I can only guess and highlight some potential issues:

The feedback mechanism, particularly the connection of R3 and C1, might not be providing appropriate feedback for hysteresis. In typical Schmitt Triggers, a direct resistor connection from the output to the input stage (in this case, base of Q1) provides the hysteresis. Here, C1 might be causing some unexpected behavior. In Schmitt Triggers, hysteresis is usually achieved without the use of capacitors in the feedback loop.

The biasing resistors R1 and R2 set the operating point for Q1. If they're not chosen correctly, Q1 might not be in the active region or might not be switching as expected.

Q3 is set up in a common collector (emitter follower) configuration, which provides no voltage gain but offers current gain. Ensure that the output device (in this case, xsc1) doesn't require a voltage level shift or amplification that this configuration cannot provide.

So, for a basic Schmitt Trigger, you might want to remove C1 and connect R3 directly from the base of Q1 to the output (collector of Q3). This would create a direct feedback path and introduce hysteresis. Ensure that the values of R1 and R2 are appropriate to set Q1 in its active region. You might need to experiment or calculate appropriate values to ensure proper thresholds.